# Angular - trying import angular template shows 404 error

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-router

i searched the whole SO for any solution for this problem, every answer is the same: check if relative path to your template is correct. my problem is, i'm testing all possible paths, in different folders and that's no matter, in all folders my template is not being located, returning a 404 error.

**Console Tab**
[image]

**Network tab**
[image]

my **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  watch: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        publicPath: './dist'
                    }
                },
                "css-loader"
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                {loader: "style-loader"},
                {loader: "css-loader"},
                {loader: "sass-loader"}
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(html)$/,
            use: [{ 
                loader:'raw-loader'
            }]          
        }
    ]
    },
    stats: {
        errorDetails: true,
        errors: true
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        compress: true,
        port: 9000,
        publicPath: '/',
        watchContentBase: true,
        hot: true,
        inline: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "app.css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

my **index.js**

```
import angular from 'angular'
import uirouter from '@uirouter/angularjs'
//import uirouterStateHelper from 'angular-ui-router.statehelper'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

angular.module('petApp', [uirouter])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {      
    // For any unmatched url, send to /
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')

    var homeState = {
      name: 'home',
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: './test.html',
      controller: 'HomeController'
    }

    $stateProvider.state(homeState);
  }).controller('HomeController', HomeController)


  function HomeController ($scope, $http) {
    console.log($scope);
  }
```

Comment: try copy test.html to your dist folder , if working fine then check the webpack config rules

Comment: copied and worked... but my templates are stored under src/templates, what to do?

Comment: i'm not familar with webpack , you can google to find out. It's should be `webpack copy src to dist` or something smilar. Or try to place `options: {
                        publicPath: './dist'
                    }` after test.html loader config before using google :)

Comment: OK,i will check it out and post my answer here

Answer (score 1):

my solution was make webpack copy my templates from `src/templates/` folder to my `./dist` folder using the Copy Webpack Plugin https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin
my strugle was, when running the development server it should (or not) copy the files at run time to dist, but i used the `build` command (after set the plugin) to copy the files and now is working fine.